# ggpaired change line color based on a condition

Tags: ggplot2, highlight, ggpairs

I would like to visualize my data with the use of ggpaired. This function adds a line between paired data. However, I would like to change the color of the line based on a condition. I have the following graph and the color of the lines should be different based on a factor in the df. Could someone point me in the right direction?

All help is appreciated.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

add `line.color="my_factor"` to your ggpaired arguments. see `?ggpaired`